# Append user entered data into redirect url

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

I had a question about trying to append user entered data into a redirect url. I use a online database/fundraising company (Salsa) for supporter sign ups. I want to have a form where people can enter just their email and zip, have that submit to be saved into the database (so onsubmit redirect) and then another form will come up if that person wants to fill out more information they can but they don't have to. The 2nd form should have prefilled their email and zip so they don't have to (to link it back to database)

What I tried to use is Salsa url that autofills the signup page provided it has the field names

example http://wfc2.wiredforchange.com/o/8564/p/salsa/web/common/public/signup?signup_page_KEY=7145&Email=testing@test.tes&Zip=12345

so http://wfc2.wiredforchange.com/o/8564/p/salsa/web/common/public/signup?signup_page_KEY=7145&Email=[email]&Zip=[zip]

The only problem is that I don't know how to pull form the form the user email and zip and append it to the url. I figure I need to use javascript but I am not very good with it.

Any help with this would be great and very appreciated. Even other ideas that I might try.

Edit:

I was able to figure some out on my own but could still use some help.

​`function URL() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    window.location = "http://wfc2.wiredforchange.com/o/8564/p/salsa/web/common/public/signup?signup_page_KEY=7145&Email=" + email;
}​`

I used

onsubmit="URL(); return false;" in 
So...

```
<form action="org2.salsalabs.com/save" ; method="POST" name="data" onsubmit="genURL(); false" >
<input type="text" id="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Something like that, except it won't submit the data to the database first, it just redirects me to the 2nd form. I am guessing it has something to do with onsumbit. Is there a way to have the data be submitted to the database first then redirect to the other form?

Answer (score 0):

I would first have an XmlHttpRequest to your database with the information and then do the window.location redirect that you have already figured out when the request is complete. This is what it would look like in code.

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    Email: <input id="email" type="text" name="Email" /><br />
    Zip: <input id="zip" type="text" name="Zip" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="sign_up_page_KEY" value="7145" />
    <input type="button" onclick="saveData()" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function saveData() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { // Triggered when the information is done saving to your database
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
            window.location = "http://wfc2.wiredforchange.com/o/8564/p/salsa/web/common/public/signup?signup_page_KEY=7145&Email=" + email + "&Zip=" + zip;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "org2.salsalabs.com/save", false);
    xmlhttp.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"))); // Sends a post request to org2.salsalabs.com/save with all the data from the form with id="myForm"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did try this originally (something really similar) but it does not save it into the database which is what I needed it to. 

I would like it to be able to save just their email and zip and then they can fill out additional information if they want to but it is not required. If they go to the second page, I don't want them to just leave it because they don't know they have to submit it there.

Comment: I was trying to figure a way to use redirect so that the form was submitted and then it was redirected to http://wfc2.wiredforchange.com/o/8564/p/salsa/web/common/public/signup?signup_page_KEY=7145&Email=[email] where the email was filled in with whatever the person put so on the second form it would be filled already.

Comment: @Kara I am confused as to exactly where the form gets submitted to before you redirect to that link.

Comment: I left off a part of the form, I probably should not have,

<form action="http://org2.salsalabs.com/save" method="POST" name="data" onsubmit="genURL(); false" >

That is my problem at this point, I get it to redirect but it does not send it to the database first.

Comment: @Kara Thanks for the additional information, I have edited my answer accordingly. I hope that this solves your problem.

Comment: I will try it now and update when I have implemented. Thanks!

Comment: I set up the code and hitting the submit button does not do anything.

Comment: @Kara Oops, I also made a mistake in my code. `if(xmlhttp.readystate == 4)` should actually be `if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4)` with a captial 's'.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything wrong, I also put it here http://jsfiddle.net/CFHtG/122/ and it is working similarly too the way it works on the site. I don't think it has anything to do with it but I had forgotten the form needs to have an organization_KEY but that shouldn't make it not do anything right? Sorry I took awhile, I am trying to figure this out on my own before bothering others!

Comment: Your fiddle is trying to send a request to `http://fiddle.jshell.net/CFHtG/122/show/org2.salsalabs.com/save` which is definitely not what you want. Even if you add a `http://` to your open call, it will still not work because modern browsers do not support cross-origin requests. try replacing your save url with `/echo/html` for testing in jsfiddle. Also, you need to captialize the s in readyState. Here is an [example for you](http://jsfiddle.net/scribblemaniac/539er/). It is always a good idea to try and figure things out for yourself, but sometimes we just need help ;)

Comment: I see, updating it to readyState did make submitting work and it does redirect to the correct page with the information filled out. However, it still isn't submitting it to the database. I tried a few times and no new supporters are coming through. I wonder if it has something to do with the org key that is required but I'm not sure. Here is some background info that might help specifically about salsa forms https://help.salsalabs.com/entries/21689130-Embed-a-signup-form I don't know if that helps.

Comment: According to the page  you sent me, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scribblemaniac/A93DB/) should work, unfortunately for some reason it does not. I don't have any other ideas, so I suggest checking everything (make sure your api url, organization id, and whatever else you need is correct). If you can't figure it out, you should probably try to contact Salsa for some support.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I really do appreciate it. I will give it a try and mess with it, I doubt I can get it if you didn't. I will contact salsa, but honestly thanks so much for all the time you have put into it with me.